# in-memory-web-api not responding to queries via chrome

Tags: angular

I've set up an in-mem database and registered, but getting back nothing. No errors, no 404 -- just the app intercepting it, and returning the application.

Am I suppossed to exclude 'api/' from processing somehow?

I've imported the latest package:

```
{
  "name": "spike02",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

And made a new database:

```
// ANGULAR/MODULES
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
// CORE/SERVICES
import { DiagnosticsTracingService, TraceLevel } from "./core/services/diagnostics.tracing.service"


@Injectable()
export class InMemDemoDbDatabaseService implements InMemoryDbService {

    constructor(private diagnosticsTracingService: DiagnosticsTracingService) {
        //super();
    }

    public createDb() {

     let heroes = [
          { id: '1', name: 'Windstorm' },
          { id: '2', name: 'Bombasto' },
          { id: '3', name: 'Magneta' },
          { id: '4', name: 'Tornado' }
        ];
        return {heroes};
    }
}
```

This is imported as:

```
// MODULES/ANGULAR
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule, InMemoryBackendConfig } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
// IMPORTANT: Only needed for Dev Demo:
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

//MODULES/CORE/SERVICES
import { DateTimeService } from '../core/services/datetime.service';
import { GuidService } from '../core/services/guid.service';
import { DiagnosticsTracingService } from '../core/services/diagnostics.tracing.service';
import { EnvironmentService } from '../core/services/environment.service';
import { NetworkService } from '../core/services/network.service';
import { CommunicationService } from '../core/services/communication.service';

import { RepositoryService } from '../core/services/repository.service';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../core/services/authentication.service';
import { AuthorisationService } from '../core/services/authorisation.service';
import { PrincipalService } from '../core/services/principal.service';
import { TenantService } from '../core/services/tenant.service';
import { SessionService } from '../core/services/session.service';

import { NavigationService } from '../core/services/navigation.service';

import { NotificationService } from '../core/services/notification.service';

import { SearchService } from '../core/services/search.service';

//MODULES/FOO/SERVICES
import { InMemDemoDbDatabaseService } from '../inMemoryDatabase';

// ROUTING/APP
import { ROUTES } from "./app.routes";

import { Constants } from "./app.constants";
// 
import { AppComponent } from './app.root';

// App views
import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';
import { FooModule } from '../foo/foo.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    JsonpModule,
    HttpModule,
    // IMPORTANT: ONLY needed for development to emulate API endpoint:
    //using  InMemoryBackendConfig
    //InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemDemoDbDatabaseService, {apiBase:'api2/'}),
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemDemoDbDatabaseService),

    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),

    CoreModule,
    FooModule,
  ],
  providers: [

    // MODULES/CORE/SERVICES:
    DateTimeService,
    GuidService,
    DiagnosticsTracingService,
    EnvironmentService/* can be lower than app root? */,
    NetworkService/* can be lower than app root? */,
    CommunicationService,
    RepositoryService,
    AuthenticationService/* can be lower than app root? */,
    AuthorisationService/* can be lower than app root? */,
    PrincipalService,
    TenantService,
    SessionService,
    NavigationService /* can be lower than app root? */,
    NotificationService,
    SearchService,

    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },

    { provide: Constants, useValue: Constants }

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And the following is the routes -- which may be intercepting it:

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

// The Views which act as Frames to 'children' routing (they render a nested 'router-outlet' element)
import { ViewLayoutBlankView } from "../core/view.layouts/view.layout.blank.view";
import { ViewLayoutDefaultView } from "../core/view.layouts/view.layout.default.view";

//The children Views that are rendered in the above Parent View Layouts:
import { LandingViewComponent } from "../foo/views/landing.views/landing.view";
import { UserLoginView } from "../core/views/user/login/user.login.view";
import { UserRegisterView } from "../core/views/user/register/user.register.view";
import { AltBrowseViewComponent } from "../foo/views/alt.views/alt.browse.view";
import { FooMainItemBrowseView } from "../foo/views/main.item.views/foo.main.item.browse.view";
import { FooMainItemViewView } from "../foo/views/main.item.views/foo.main.item.view.view";
import { FooMainItemEditView } from "../foo/views/main.item.views/foo.main.item.edit.view";


import { IsAuthenticatedActivationGuard } from '../core/guards/is.authenticated.activation.guard';

import { Status404View } from "../core/views/status/status.404.view";


import { ExampleViews } from "../core/views/example/example.views";
import { ExampleButtonsView } from "../core/views/example/example.buttons.view";
import { ExampleIconsView } from "../core/views/example/example.icons.view";



export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    // Main redirect
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'landingView', pathMatch: 'full'
    },

    // App views
    {
        path: '', component: ViewLayoutDefaultView,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'landingView', component: LandingViewComponent, data: {menuName: 'primary', titleResourceKey: 'App/Navigation/Titles/DashboardView', className: 'fa fa-th-large' }
            },
            {
                path: 'altView', component: AltBrowseViewComponent, data: {menuName: 'primary',  titleResourceKey:'App/Navigation/Titles/AltView', className: 'fa fa-desktop' } //, canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedActivationGuard]
            },
        ]
    },
    // App views
    {
        path: 'foo', component: ViewLayoutDefaultView,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'browse', component: FooMainItemBrowseView, data: {menuName: 'primary',  titleResourceKey:'App/Navigation/Titles/FooView', className: 'fa fa-desktop' } //, canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedActivationGuard]
            },
            {
                path: 'view', component: FooMainItemViewView, data: { } //, canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedActivationGuard]
            },
            {
                path: 'edit', component: FooMainItemEditView, data: { } //, canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedActivationGuard]
            }
        ]
    },


    {
        path: 'user', component: ViewLayoutBlankView,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: UserLoginView, data: {menuName: 'primary',  titleResourceKey: 'App/Navigation/Titles/UserLoginView',  className: 'fa fa-sign-in' } },
            { path: 'register', component: UserRegisterView, data: {menuName: 'primary',  titleResourceKey: 'App/Navigation/Titles/UserRegisterView', className: 'fa fa-pencil' } },
            { path: 'retrieve', component: UserRegisterView, data: { } }
            //{ path: 'user/logout', component: UserRegisterView , data : {glyph:'sign-out'}}
        ]
    },


    {
        path: 'examples', component: ViewLayoutDefaultView,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'list', component: ExampleViews, data: {title: 'Examples',  menuName: 'primary', className: 'fa fa-th-large' }
            },
            {
                path: 'buttons', component: ExampleButtonsView, data: {title: 'Buttons',  menuName: 'examples', className: 'fa fa-th-large' }
            },
            {
                path: 'icons', component: ExampleIconsView, data: {title: 'Icons',  menuName: 'examples', className: 'fa fa-th-large' }
            }
        ]
    },

    // Handle all other routes
    //{ path: '**', component: Status404View }
];
```

Should I be messing around with angular-cli.json (excluding a path?)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "spike02"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "assets/styles/styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
         "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What URL are you using?

Comment: Hi, peeskillet,

Comment: Hi, peeskillet. I'm using the default angular/cli http://localhost:4200/ base url.   The app was a fresh angular-cli based TS creation as per the tutorials. Totally in TypeScript (no idea where the JS files are going as they never appear on the drive). When I reference the TOR sample I downloaded, I noticed it's a bit different. TS + JS. And a systemjs.angular-loader.js -- which mentions the in memory-web-api module. But wondering as to whether that was manually built, or automatically generated from another source (angular-cli.json). As you can tell...first time at Angular TS (never did ng 1)

Comment: Sorry - just pinged. For the api I'm using http://localhost/api/heroes

Comment: Need coffee!!! One last time: http://localhost:4200/api/heroes

Comment: Yea I'm not sure. It looks like it should work

Answer (score 1):

I'm a nitwit Of course it won't work from chrome's address bar!

For some reason, even though the documentation was being explicit that it was intercepting and wrapping the http *client* within the app, I was...expecting it to work on the server side (angular-cli server).

In other words, it works fine only when invoked via code from *within an Angular app* -- but does not work outside of the context of an app's wrapped http client.

In other words...it works just fine and always did.

Tip: 
because it intercepts all calls coming from the client, and by default does not handle 'unknown' urls, calls to static files start to mysteriously fail. You have to change the config to allow unkonwn urls to actually leave the *client*, and get to the server:

```
...
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemDemoDbDatabaseService, {passThruUnknownUrl: true, apiBase:'api/'})
...
```

Thanks!